# Tweaking ADW Launcher for custom icon sets

Tags: android, launcher, android-theme, android-launcher

Recently, i took up the idea to create a custom launcher for an android phone.
After performing an extensive search for the resources which would help me to accomplish the task, i found out not much of help is available.
Many posts on this site suggest to study ADW Launcher,Homescreen sample from sdk and some other opensource Launchers.
So i took the ADW Launcher and tried to give it a shot.
My questions are :

- Suggest me, what are the key aspects i should concentrate on in this app.
- Is it possible to add my custom icon set in this app itself without using the themer or template available, which suggest using [this](http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/wiki/ADWThemeGuide#Custom_Icon_Naming_-_Video_and_Databases) procedure.